# Can an AWS Fargate Service have 0 tasks running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I currently have a Fargate cluster that contains a service. This service always has 1 task running and is polling from SQS. The service will scale the number of tasks if SQS grows/shrinks. However, the task has a lot of idle time, where there are no messages in the queue. To save on costs, is it possible to make the service go down to 0 task?

I have been trying to do this and the service will always try to start at least 1 task.

If this is not possible, then would it be best practice for me to not use a service and have a CloudWatch alarm on SQS and just create a task directly in the cluster when the size is greater than 0, and then shut down the task when the SQS is back to 0? Essentially mimicking the functionality of a service.

Comment: I think its possible. I remember having similar issue. I solved (I think I solved it) by using [step scaling policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-applicationautoscaling-scalingpolicy-stepscalingpolicyconfiguration.html) with `ExactCapacity` as `AdjustmentType` type. When value of messages in queue was 0 the `ExactCapacity` was 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62721171/3288890 that might help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can also use a `Target Tracking Policy` that allow you to scale more efficiently than a `Step Scaling Policy`.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html for more details (it's about EC2 but works for ECS as well).

Answer (score 0):

From the scenario you are describing, I don't believe you need an ECS service in place. Instead, what you should do is:

1. Have the SQS queue configured to have a trigger to a Lambda function
2. That Lambda function takes the message from the queue, and executes an ECS task on a given cluster. Remember to pass the original message as the parameter to the Docker container.

Example with Python:

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Extract the message from the SQS event
    sqs_message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])
    
    # ECS cluster and task details
    ecs_cluster = 'your-ecs-cluster-name'
    ecs_task_definition = 'your-ecs-task-definition'
    
    # Create ECS client
    ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs')
    
    # Run ECS task with the SQS message as a parameter
    response = ecs_client.run_task(
        cluster=ecs_cluster,
        taskDefinition=ecs_task_definition,
        launchType='FARGATE',  # Or 'EC2' depending on your setup
        networkConfiguration={
            'awsvpcConfiguration': {
                'subnets': ['subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'],
                'securityGroups': ['sg-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'],
            }
        },
        overrides={
            'containerOverrides': [
                {
                    'name': 'your-container-name',
                    'command': [sqs_message]  # Pass the SQS message as a command parameter
                },
            ],
        },
    )
    
    # Print the response from ECS
    print(response)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('ECS task execution triggered successfully!')
    }
```

**I believe you also should consider the idea of executing your code directly on a Lambda function but the ECS task is the best alternative if you anticipate it to run for more than 15 minutes.**